# copy_from_user is fetching unexpected data

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I want to use the write sycall for copying a struct
from userspace to kernel.
In both user and kernel space, the struct is defined as

```
struct packet{
    unsigned char packet[256];
    int length;
}__attribute__ ((packed));
```

User space uses a local variable of type struct packet and passes it to the write syscall.

```
struct packet p;
/* ... (fill in data)  */
printf("packet.length: %d\n",packet.length); /* looks correct */
result = write(uartFD, &p, sizeof(struct packet));
```

The kernel side looks like this, checking for correct length is done, just removed from example.

```
/* write syscall */
ssize_t packet_write(
    struct file *file_ptr,
    const char __user *user_buffer,
    size_t count, loff_t *position)
{

struct packet p;
int retval;

if (copy_from_user((void*)&p, user_buffer, sizeof(struct packet))){
    retval = -EACCES;
    goto err;
}

/* looks wrong - different numbers like 96373062 or 96373958 */
printk("packet length: %d\n",p.length);
```

The opposite direction using read sycall is working as expected:

```
 /* read syscall */
struct packet p;
/* ... (fill in data)  */
copy_to_user(user_buffer, (void*)&p, sizeof(struct packet));
```

---

```
/* userspace */
read(uartFD, (void*)&packet, sizeof(struct packet));
```

What am I doing wrong with write syscall?

Comment: Do some more debugging:  What if you write a 256-byte buffer filled with a count (0,1,2,3, etc)?  What if you send just the length as a 4-byte integer?  Is it a formatting or alignment problem or a fundamental problem with getting the data across the user/kernel boundary?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This is solved - it was my own silly. Both copying an integer and an unsigned char buffer separately was working, so it had to be something about the struct.

One site was packed, the other was not... reusing old code...